# javax.servlet.ServletContext is being loaded from multiple dependencies in springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets

So I have this springboot application which I'm migrating from a WAS to a springboot setup. And I have a couple of JSPs which has to be configured. To accomodate these I added the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.22</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The application already came with the following dependency which is being used throughout the application:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
      <artifactId>com.ibm-jaxrpc-client</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The issue I'm facing is that both these dependencies (jaxrpc-client and tomcat-embed-jasper) have javax.servlet.ServletContext classes in them which is causing the following error:

```
The method's class, javax.servlet.ServletContext, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/.m2/repository/com/ibm/com.ibm-jaxrpc-client/6.0/com.ibm-jaxrpc-client-6.0.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.30/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/.m2/repository/com/ibm/com.ibm-jaxrpc-client/6.0/com.ibm-jaxrpc-client-6.0.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.servlet.ServletContext
```

I can't afford to remove any of these dependencies. jaxrpc-client is being referenced in the code already in too many places and I need tomcat-embed-jasper to render my jsp pages. I can't exclude the ServletContext class since its not a dependency(If I'm not wrong about the concept of exclusion). Please help with with a way forward with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with IBM's jaxrpc client, but I assume, you have this exception in runtime, when trying to load the application.

In this case consider the following approaches:

1. Use another jax-rpc client library
2. Consider Loading the code that uses this library with the different class-loader (you'll have to create one classloader for this) to avoid the clash
3. Kind of paraphrasing the second option. You can "play" (override the order of loading of specific classes) with spring boot classloader as described in [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-classloader-and-class-override)

I know, this is too general answer, but hopefully its still helpful.
The first solution is by far the easiest way I can think of.

The second solution is doable, however it pretty much depends on how exactly the code that uses the jax rpc client is loaded and used.